# Ruby on Rails, method undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to ruby on rails. I'm trying to make a text field to assign one of my variables (end_date), but I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `end_date' for #<Quiz:0x007fccd1e0f9c0>
```

Here's my code:

```
<%# Main Canvas where cardes places %>
<div class="column large-11" id="main">
  <%= form_for @quiz do |q| %>
    <%= q.label :quiz_name %>
    <%= q.text_field :quiz_name %>
    <%= q.label :end_date %>
    <%= q.text_field :end_date %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'selected', 'none' %>
    <%= q.hidden_field :classroom_id, value: @classroom_id%>

  <%= q.submit "Create Quiz", class: "expanded button" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form_tag("/quiz/#{@classroom_id}/copy", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label :id, "ID" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "id", "" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Copy Quiz By ID", class: "expanded button" %>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

Comment: Has the Quiz model the attribute `end_date`?

Comment: Sebastian is basically asking, is there an end_date column for quiz?  If so, active_record would have made a getter/setter for you automagically.  If end_date isn't meant to be a column but just some form data to manipulate and pass along you can add "attr_accessor :end_date" to your quiz model file to setup virtual attribute.

Comment: thank you everyone! I was incorrectly trying to manually add the attribute to an already existing model– whoops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me break down how these different pieces relate to one-another, which hopefully will make this easier for you to troubleshoot.

```
<%= form_for @quiz do |q| %>
```

Here you are invoking `form_for` to create a form bound to the `@quiz` object. It yields a **[form builder](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object)** object as the argument `q`.

```
<%= q.text_field :quiz_name %>
```

Here you are calling the [`text_field`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field) method on the form builder with the field named `quiz_name`. This means it will generate a text input, and call the `quiz_name` method on `@quiz` to find the current value.

So given that background, it should be clear why you are seeing this error:

```
<%= q.text_field :end_date %>
```

You are telling the form builder to call `@quiz.end_date` for the value of this field, but that method does not exist.

You have not given enough code samples for us to determine why you expect this method to exist. Perhaps this is a field you've added to the quizzes table, but haven't yet run the migration? Is this supposed to be a virtual attribute on `Quiz`? Or perhaps you just want to send a field that isn't connected to the `Quiz` model inside this form. (You can do that with a separate set of helpers, in this case [`text_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag), that give you more flexibility in where the data comes from).